# Deleting entire row angular 2 material?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

JSON

```
[
  { position: 1, name: 'test', value: 1.0079, symbol: 'HHH' },
  { position: 2, name: 'test2', value: 4.0026, symbol: 'BBB' },
  { position: 3, name: 'test3', value: 6.941, symbol: 'BB' },
  { position: 4, name: 'test4', value: 9.0122, symbol: 'CC' },
]
```

TS

```
  isAllSelected() {
    const numSelected = this.selection.selected.length;
    const numRows = this.dataSource.data.length;
    return numSelected === numRows;
  }

  removeSelectedRows() {
     this.selection.selected.forEach(item => {
      let index: number = this.data.findIndex(d => d === item);
      console.log(this.data.findIndex(d => d === item));
      this.dataSource.data.splice(index,1);

      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.dataSource.data);
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      });
    });
    this.selection = new SelectionModel<Element>(true, []);
  }

  /** Selects all rows if they are not all selected; otherwise clear selection. */
  masterToggle() {
    this.isAllSelected() ?
      this.selection.clear() :
      this.dataSource.data.forEach(row => this.selection.select(row));
  }
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Checkbox Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
      </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <button mat-icon-button color="#b71c1c">
                    <mat-icon aria-label="Delete">delete</mat-icon>
                  </button>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

     <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> value </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.value}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
             (click)="selection.toggle(row)">
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>


</div>
```

i want to delete the entire row using one click button
Explanation -> when i click on delete button the entire row should get delete but here I'm doing API call for example when i delete any row it will send name to the API!

here it is my stackbliz demo -https://stackblitz.com/edit/delete-rows-mat-table-f5f7tr?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always better to check for `index != -1`

```
removeSelectedRows(row) {
    let index = ELEMENT_DATA.findIndex(x => x.position == row.position);

    if (index != -1) {
      ELEMENT_DATA.splice(index, 1)
    }
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);
}
```

Comment: actually that delete icon there was a check box and when i click on particular check box it gets the CODE column value and on the basis of code column value I'm deleting the entire row! but right now i dont have check box so when i want to delete the row and click on the delete icon the row of code value get pass to the API how?

Comment: look at here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbf9kz-ex9qcb?file=app/table-basic-example.ts

Comment: Do you want to delete a row on checkbox check?

Comment: Done! but add if condition!

Comment: Pimple could you look at the my new Qn?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

HTML:

```
<!-- Checkbox Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
    <button mat-icon-button color="#b71c1c" (click)="removeSelectedRow(row)">
      <mat-icon aria-label="Delete">delete</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

TS:

```
removeSelectedRow(row) {
    //const index = this.data.findIndex(obj => obj === row);
    const index = this.data.findIndex(obj => obj.codeData == row.codeData);
    this.data.splice(index, 1);
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.dataSource.data);
}
```

[**StackBlitz HERE**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-deleting-entire-row-angular-2-material?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts)

Result:

[image]

Comment: The findIndex() method returns the index of the first element in the array that satisfies the provided testing function.
And this.data refers to your data => data = Object.assign(ELEMENT_DATA);

Comment: each row contain uniq value and that uniq value is my this.codeData value so i want to delete this row in the reference of codeData value so how can i pass this value here

Comment: In this case, when deleting, you get the object's codeData:
`const index = this.data.findIndex(obj => obj.codeData === row.codeData);`

I added a codeData to your data:
`{ codeData: 'ABC', position: 1, name: 'test', value: 1.0079, symbol: 'HHH' },...`

You can go to the [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-deleting-entire-row-angular-2-material?file=app%2Ftable-selection-example.ts), I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

add a function for deleting the row:

```
  deleteRow(row) {
    this.dataSource.data.splice(row.position-1, 1);
    this.dataSource =  new MatTableDataSource<Element>(this.dataSource.data);
  }
```

and in the HTML call this function when the delete button is clicked

```
<button (click)="deleteRow(row)" mat-icon-button color="#b71c1c">
      <mat-icon aria-label="Delete">delete</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Comment: @PrashantPimpale could you please look in to my new Qn sorry but you always gve me a simple answers!